# Database Field, Required

Tags: php, database, printing, required

I was trying to ask about required field print out to make sure its working.
    But the question was rated so badly to prevent me from asking more questions.
    this was the solution for it, try to rate it up so i can remove block.

```
 <?php   if (empty($_POST) === false) {  
    $required_fields = array(
        'username', 'password', 'password_again', 
        'first_name', 'last_name', 
        'email', 'bday', 
        'county', 'zip', 'gender'
    );
    // create our output array
    $output = array(); 
    $altOutput = array();

    // this adds the post value to our output array
    // using a foreach loop
    // it simply looks for the POST by the field in your array
    // if it's found and not empty, it will add to our new output array
    foreach ($required_fields as $field) 
        if (!empty($_POST[$field])) {
            // this adds the field to your new output array
            $output[] = $_POST[$field];
            // this removes it from the POST array
            unset($_POST[$field]);
        }

    // now output the new array having only the fields you want
    echo '<pre>', print_r($output, true), '</pre>';

    // if you want to print out what's left over
    echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST, true), '</pre>';}
```

Comment: That's what print_r does. http://us1.php.net/print_r

Comment: Yup. you're doing exactly what it's supposed to do. Am I to assume those fields in the array our the `$_POST` fields you want?

Comment: Because you are printing the $_POST variable? You don't actually do anything with your $required_fields array

Comment: Well yes , but it shows all the other fields !!! when i printed it out , u can go check it yourself ... www.modelcharm.com/register.php , just submit and see what it print

Comment: does what you ask of it, this is a surprise?

Comment: im watching phpacademy and thats what have been written on the tut !

Comment: Your PHP syntax is totall broken anyways. You're populating your array with a large number of undefined constants... not strings. You also don't USE that array in any way. If you want $_POST filtered to show only the fields listed in the array, then you're missing a large amount of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
So, I just noticed, despite having fully answered the question. Despite even 
being selected as correct answer. The 3 upvotes I had gained on this lost the 
final mark today, thus putting this answer at 0. I also noticed this question 
is now marked closed. Could someone please explain to me why an answered 
question is closed after the fact and why the selected correct answer is 
steadily being downvoted?
```

---

It's doing exactly as you said because that's what you have set up for it to do.

Quick break down:

```
<?php // init php code
    // here you check if post has anything in it's array
    // that's right, $_POST will be an ARRAY
    if (empty($_POST) === false) { // same as `if (!empty($_POST)) {` except longer
        // here you simply set an array variable
        $required_fields = array(username, password, password_again, first_name, last_name, email, bday, county, zip, gender);
        // here you're one lining it, but suffice it to say, you're sending a <pre> tag to the browser
        // which helps to make what `print_r` produces more readable as you're printing an array
        echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST, true), '</pre>';
```

---

As you may have noticed, you're not even using your array, `$required_fields`.

### Now

If you would like to print each one of those fields and only those fields AS AN ARRAY, then you need to make it so

```
<?php   
if (empty($_POST) === false) {  
        $required_fields = array(
            'username', 'password', 'password_again', 
            'first_name', 'last_name', 
            'email', 'bday', 
            'county', 'zip', 'gender'
        );

        // create our output array
        $output = array(); 
        // $altOutput = array(); // not used in this example

        // this adds the post value to our output array
        // using a foreach loop
        // it simply looks for the POST by the field in your array
        // if it's found and not empty, it will add to our new output array
        foreach ($required_fields as $field) 
            if (!empty($_POST[$field])) {
                // this adds the field to your new output array
                $output[] = $_POST[$field];
                // this removes it from the POST array
                unset($_POST[$field]);
            }

        // now output the new array having only the fields you want
        echo '<pre>', print_r($output, true), '</pre>';

        // if you want to print out what's left over
        echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST, true), '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks u did a great job :) ... u also added  $output variable to print the result , thanks for your help .

Comment: No problem. IF you need more help understanding, just let me know.

Comment: I think u something need to be edited here , the ones inside the arrays are required to be filled but i got other ones who are not required , after using ur code the other fields are not printed !

Comment: So you want the other fields in a separate output?

Comment: @Eng-Amir Made a couple changes, does that help what you expect?

Comment: Yes that's moving good now , i hope things can move on now ... thanks for your help , if i need anything i will tell u

Comment: hey @SpYk3HH, what does the notation $output[] mean, or what is it called? In particular the []. I've tried searching for it, but searching for brackets isn't very helpful.

Comment: @NickM *Just got your comments* I see you figured it out. Yeah, anytime in php, you establish an empty array like `$output = array();`, you can *push* to that array with a simple `$output[] = "value";`.  `[]` is simply the next `index` key available based on a `0 index`. This means you can also make `key` assignments just as easy, such as `$output['newKey'] = 'value';` Viola! Now the array has an item with an index of `newKey`! PHP is extremely similar to JS, just a few different characters here and there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are having a little trouble understanding the code. Your `$required_fields` array isn't even being used again. I took spend some time making this work:

```
$required_fields = array(username, password, password_again, first_name, last_name, email, bday, county, zip, gender);
foreach($required_fields as $field) {
    print $_POST[$field];
}
```

Notice that we are looping through the `$required_fields` array and pulling the individual data from `$_POST`.

Comment: @feeela I didn't include a check to see if the field is set. I assumed that they were.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a complete example, that cancels further execution if one or more fields are empty and prints out the names of those fields to the user:

```
if( !empty( $_POST ) )
{
    $requiredFields = array(
        'username', 
        'password', 
        'password_again', 
        'first_name', 
        'last_name', 
        'email', 
        'bday', 
        'county', 
        'zip', 
        'gender',
    );
    $missingFields = array();

    foreach( $requiredFields as $fieldName )
    {
        if( empty( $_POST[$fieldName] ) )
        {
            $missingFields[] = $fieldName;
        }
    }

    if( !empty( $missingFields ) )
    {
        echo sprintf( 'You have not filled out the following fields: %s.', implode( ', ', $missingFields ) );
        return;
    }
}
```